# How can I validate PySpark Dataframe schema is obey to a particular structure?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to create a unit test that validates the Dataframe schema by comparing it to a particular schema structure I created, how can I do that?

For example, I have a `df` and schema -

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("id",StringType(),True),
    StructField("name",StringType(),True)
 ])
```

I want to validate that `df.schema == schema`

Comment: You can use `df.schema` to get the schema

Comment: do you want to validate no.of column or column name or column name with type?

Comment: Column name with type. I guess it can be done by a loop over the column and checking each of them, but I'm wondering if a better more convenient way is existing